# creating multiple arrays by splitting a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Lets say I have an `@assortment` of numbers in a hash, e.g. 1 to 100.
Each number in the `@assortment` can have a status of `:free`, or `:used`.

An example `@assortment` could be: 
    { 1 => :free, 2 => :free, 3=> :used etc ... }

Lets say I want to split the `@assortment` up based on the used numbers, and extract the free numbers into their *own* hash (or an array or hashes?)

For example, for an `@assortment` of 1 to 100, if numbers 25 and 75 were 'used' and the rest were 'free', then the result would be 3 new hashes of all the free values:

```
1 to 24
26 to 74
76 to 100
```

Similarly, lets say we have a different `@assortmen`t, with numbers 1 to 100, but I want to extract numbers 20 to 80, but numbers 30, 31, 32 and 40 are used then the result is like this :

```
hash1 -> 20 to 29
hash2 ->33 to 39
hash3 -> 41 to 80
```

Is there a nice functional way to do this in Ruby, where I can pass in a complete `@assortment` of numbers, and an optional range to extract and get the resulting hashes, perhaps in an array?

I guess the original hash gets broken up or split based on the `:used` elements...

If you were to loop through the hash, then every free number would be added to a new hash (e.g. hash1) until you reach a used number. Keep going through the loop until you reach a free number, this and all subsequent free numbers get added to a new hash (hash2). Keep this going until you have all the free numbers in new hashes...

Comment: Can you add some sample data in Ruby format? It's not quite clear from your question what the input and output would be. Do you mean something like  `{ 1 => :free, 2 => :used, ... }`?

Comment: yes assume it is in that format, I will add to the question

Comment: Also add the expected output format, it helps a lot.

Comment: consider the output format to be the same as the input format, but the results either in separate hashes (if possible) or else add all the new hashes to an array if thats easier??

Comment: The output format can't be the same since you want it split up somehow. Please make an effort to describe the desired result. Your example with `hash1, hash2` is not sufficient. Is that an array of arrays of hashes? Are they necessarily grouped as contiguous blocks?

Comment: I really just want to split the original hash into separate parts, the splitting point being the used numbers.  Apologies if this is not clear, I'm not sure how to describe it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@assortment = (20..50).to_a.product([:free]).to_h
[30,31,32,40].each { |n| @assortment[n] = :used }
@assortment
  # => {20=>:free, 21=>:free, 22=>:free, 23=>:free, 24=>:free, 25=>:free,
  #     26=>:free, 27=>:free, 28=>:free, 29=>:free, 30=>:used, 31=>:used,
  #     32=>:used, 33=>:free, 34=>:free, 35=>:free, 36=>:free, 37=>:free,
  #     38=>:free, 39=>:free, 40=>:used, 41=>:free, 42=>:free, 43=>:free,
  #     44=>:free, 45=>:free, 46=>:free, 47=>:free, 48=>:free, 49=>:free, 50=>:free}
```

**Return an array of hashes**

```
@assortment.reject { |_,v| v == :used }.
            slice_when { |(a,_),(b,_)| b > a+1 }.
            to_a.
            map(&:to_h)
  #=> [{20=>:free, 21=>:free,...29=>:free},
  #    {33=>:free, 34=>:free,...39=>:free},
  #    {41=>:free, 42=>:free,...50=>:free}]
```

See [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject) (which returns a hash) and [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).

**Return an array of arrays**

Having a hash whose values are all the same doesn't seem very useful. If you'd prefer returning an array of array, just drop `to_h`.

```
arr = @assortment.reject { |_,v| v == :used }.
            keys.
            slice_when { |a,b| b > a+1 }.
            to_a
  #=> [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
  #    [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
  #    [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]]
```

**Return an array of ranges**

A third option is to return an array of ranges. To do that map each of `arr`'s elements (arrays) to a range:

```
arr.map { |f,*_,l| f..l }
  #=> [20..29, 33..39, 41..50]
```

The first element of `arr` passed to the block is `[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]`. The three block variables are computed using *parallel assignement*:

```
f,*b,l = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29] 
f #=> 20 
_ #=> [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28] 
l #=> 29
```

I wish to underscore that I've used an underscore for the second block variable to underscore that it is not used in the block calculation.

Comment: Looks great! Would this differ much if @assortment was an active record result in rails, so I assume would that be an array with each element of the array being a hash of attributes like :number => "1", :status => "free".... I guess I convert the active record result to a hash, see the example here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html

Comment: So I guess it would be an array of hashes, rather than a hash. Would that require iteration? Or could it be flattened perhaps

Comment: I don't know Rails, so perhaps a reader could answer the first question. If I returned an array of hashes what would the hashes look like? Would all values be `:free`?

Comment: They would ask be free numbers, but in different hashes based on the splitting via the used